# jQuery toggle menu has issues with sub-item CSS

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, menu

We had a bad experience with a developer not sticking to timelines and what-not so we had to drop them. That being said, we're completing the site on our own and only have a few items left.  One of which is a JQuery based navigation toggle that he made... it works fine for the main level of items but when you get into sub menu items, it stops using the appropriate CSS.  I'm thinking this is a basic "add this to CSS" answer, but I'm not versed in CSS well enough to figure it out.

The CSS and what I think is the JS calling it can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/C8vwJ/
The issue can be seen here: http://74.124.14.50/connecting-point/outreach/ (note the + "toggle open" graphic on the sub-item beneath "Outreach" is on the "Y" of "BeYond"... so it's not being CSS'd to the right as it should be.

Any ideas?  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line into your CSS file.

```
.widget-area .current_page_item .page_item .toggle { right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trouble in these lines of css code - style.css line 1291:

```
.widget-area .current-menu-item .toggle, .widget-area .current_page_item .toggle {
    right: 10em;
}
```

If I try to change this value both '+' link and '-' link moving. Try to brake these properties. I tried to do

```
<div class="toggle" style="right: 0pt;"></div>
```

(this can be applied by classname, not inline css)